# How can I detect a Select option change when using jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-select

Validating a form on HTML using JavaScript.

I have a select box (as shown below) and I'm trying to detect an on change event but jQuery doesn't detect a change.

I'm using with jQuery mobile, but for this element I'm not using the cool popup select menus, just the standard.  Is there anything else I need to do?  I've tried a number of jQuery ideas.

I have other elements on the page such as

```
<input id="Title" type="text">
```

and successfully get a change event using

```
$("#Title").change(function() { xxx }
```

How can I detect a Select option change?

### ----

EDIT: 
Here is my full code:
HTML:

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text"><span>Bralivros</span></span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        <select id="publisher">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Please Choose a Publisher</option>
            <option value="livros">livros</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c validating">
    <input size="45" maxlength="200" name="Book[Title]" id="Book_Title" type="text" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#publisher").on('change', function() {
        check_Publisher();
    });
    $("#Book_Title").change(function() {
        check_Title();
    });
});

function check_Publisher() {
    console.log("checking publisher");
}
function check_Title() {
    console.log("checking title");
}
```

Comment: This should work. Have you added the code on dom ready.

Comment: You can replace `$(element).find("option:selected").val()` by `$("#publisher option:selected").val()`. And are you sure the change is not fired ? Can you `console.log("change");` instead of your code ?

Comment: I've uised console.log, also have it in a document.ready function.  Notice that the DOM (chrome web developer) does not show the 'selected' option change when I select from the list.

Comment: See my updated code above.  I've used .on('change'), .change and .bind('change') to try and pick up the field.  Again, the DOM does not seem to update when the selection changes, the default selected item remains selected, even though visually it is not.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vEWh6/2/)

```
<select id="publisher">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Please Choose a Publisher</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

 $("#publisher").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
    var publisher = $("#publisher").val();
    alert(publisher);
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't help :( It looks like the DOM is not updating the selected element

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $("#publisher").on('change', function() {
        check_Publisher(this);
    });
    function check_Publisher(ths){
        console.log('publisher'+ths.value);// ths refers to publisher
    }
});
```

The same, you can do for your `textbox` also.

Comment: the function is not getting called to begin with.  Its not the if statement